# How to Print Dictionaries In Python

Tags: python, dictionary

```
import operator
pay = {}
lowestPay={}
averagePay={}
pay["Developers"]=[35,22,18,36]
pay["Designers"]=[25,65,24,45]
pay["Testers"]=[34,52,12,32]
userInput=int(input("How would you like the menu to be sorted?\n1 for Dictionary keys sorted in alphabetical order\n2 for Sort each list of employee’s pay rates from highest to lowest\n3 for Lowest pay level in each list sorted from highest to lowest\n4 for Average pay per department sorted from highest to lowest"))
if userInput == 1:
    for key,value in pay.items():
        sortedDictionary = sorted(pay)
    print (sortedDictionary)
if userInput == 2:
    for key,value in pay.items():
        value.sort()
        value.reverse()
        print(key,value)
if userInput == 3:
    for key,value in pay.items():
        value.sort()
        lowestPay [key]=value.pop()
        lowestPaySorted = sorted(pay.items(),key=operator.itemgetter(1),reverse=True)
    print (lowestPay)
if userInput == 4:
    for key,value in pay.items():
        average = sum(value)/len(value)
        averagePay [key]=(average)
        averagePaySorted = sorted(averagePay.items(),key=operator.itemgetter(1),reverse=True)
    for keys in averagePaySorted:
        print (keys)
        for value in averagePaySorted[keys]:
            print (value,':',cars[keys][value])
```

Above I have my program for sorting lists. I need to print the dictionary `averagePaySorted`. I am quite new to this so I am not to sure what to do as you can see I tried to attempt printing this from some other pages but I got this error:

```
  ... line 33, in <module>
    for value in averagePaySorted[keys]:
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

I have no idea what that means I need it to out look something like this

```
B
color : 3
speed : 60
A
color : 2
speed : 70
```

but this was taken from a different forum to save time

Comment: `from pprint import pprint` and then `pprint(pay)` will help you to better understand your data. Also, pray split each of your cases into a separate function; just the signatures of these functions will make your thinking clearer, and the error you're having more obvious.

Comment: you should familiarize yourself with `if/elif's` the user input cannot be four different things at one time

Comment: Thanks Padriac Didn't realise i Had done that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To print a dictionary, check out [pprint](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html).  E.g.,

```
print pformat(averagePaySorted)
```

Or, a more complete example:

```
from pprint import pformat
mydict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, c: [4, 5, 6]}
print pformat(mydict)
```

---

1. `pprint` handles nesting, and
2. advanced options are available.

E.g.,

```
print pformat(mydict, width=1)
```

produces:

```
{'a': 1,
 'b': 2,
 'c': [4,
       5,
       6]}
```

Comment: Please provide details so I can help you.  Syntax error on what line?  And which version of Python?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is because keys on this scenario is a tuple (key, value)

To print this, use something similar to

```
for key,value in list:
  print key, ':', value
```

Comment: I got a EOL error whatever that means sorry if i sound stupid i am a bit out my depth with this